# RadioGroup not getting the correct values from the radio buttons - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I followed the documentation of Material UI to create a `RadioGroup` with four different options. Each option is in a `FormControlLabel`. This is how my code looks like:

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import QuestionRadios from "./QuestionRadios";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <QuestionRadios
        firstOption={"Option 1"}
        secondOption={"Option 2"}
        thirdOption={"Option 3"}
        fourthOption={"Option 4"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

QuestionRadios.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";

export default function QuestionRadios(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset" style={{ marginLeft: 8, marginTop: 6 }}>
      <FormLabel component="legend">Choose one option.</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="option"
        name="option"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="option1"
          control={<Radio />}
          label={props.firstOption}
        />

        <FormControlLabel
          value="option2"
          control={<Radio />}
          label={props.secondOption}
        />

        <FormControlLabel
          value="option3"
          control={<Radio />}
          label={props.thirdOption}
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="option4"
          control={<Radio />}
          label={props.fourthOption}
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

When I click on the first radio button I am expecting the console to show `option1`, instead it shows an empty string. When I clicked the radio button below it then `option1` gets printed out. First click will always be an empty string and then the other buttons will show different values when clicked in different order. I really don't understand what is going on as I have followed the documentation of Material UI.

EDIT: I have updated the code and given a CodeSandBox link demonstrating the issue.

[image: Edit compassionate-leftpad-8oj3p]

Any help would be nice, thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine. `setState` is asynchronous. If you move the `console.log` (see https://codesandbox.io/s/radio-setstate-twum2?file=/src/QuestionRadios.js), you'll see that the value is changing as expected.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now